# Speeding up sampling in a graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx, numba

I've been recently working with graph sampling in Python. My working example reads as:

```
for enx, wlen in enumerate(wlen_dist):
    for j in range(wlen):
        node_container = queue.Queue(maxsize=200000000)
        node_container.put(node_name)
        tmp_walk = [] # [node_name]
        while not node_container.empty():
            nod = node_container.get()
            neighs = list(network.neighbors(nod))
            tar = random.choice(neighs)
            node_container.put(tar)
            if len(tmp_walk) > enx+1:
                break
            tmp_walk.append(tar)
       some_container.append(tmp_walk)
```

where wlen is the number of samples of path of length enx, and I am simply saving the walks to some_container (not really important here). The wlen_dist is for example:

```
[1000,500,100]
```

and here, 1000 samples of a walk of length two, 500 of length 3 and 100 of length 4 are obtained. The networkx is a networkX graph.
I was wondering, how does one speed up code like this (I am new to this part).

My ideas:

1. Use Numba and wrap individual walks into a method
2. Use Cython somehow
3. Rewrite it alltogether in C++ and call it somehow

I would be glad for any ideas and feedback, thanks!

Comment: Threading can be an easy way to speed it up since you have a list of tasks that can be completed in parallel.

Comment: Have you thought about reusing parts of the longer walks for the shorter ones? E.g. a random walk with 3 steps include two random walks with 2 steps?

Comment: Thanks, so you mean some form of caching right? This is a good idea thanks!

Comment: Just forgot, another think which worked well for me regarding speeding up my python code using `networkx` was `PyPy` (no changes to your code are needed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea often used in graph embedding is the idea of reusing parts of random walks:

If you have a random walk visiting the nodes `a_1, a_2, a_3`, you can regard this as one random walk of length 3 and 2 random walks of length 2 (`a_1, a_2` and `a_2, a_3`).

This can be generalised to longer walks, so your random walks of length 4 contain 2 random walks of length 3 and 3 random walks of length 2.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently working towards this idea, and it seems as the best (optimal) solution